# storing user id in node global variable

Tags: node.js

If I use node global variable to store a user-personal data like his user id, will this persist among instances? IE: will it risk to be overwritten by other users requests changing it's value to ids not belonging to the "current" user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, absolutely. Common practice is to get an ID of every user, and use it as an index in maps (`{}`) of all personal details.